# Calling helper function to reverse lists, then zipping lists in Haskell

Tags: list, haskell, zip, helper

I'm new to Haskell and I've been trying for hours to get these two functions to work together to produce a zipped reverse list using recursion and without built-in functions.

Here's the helper function to reverse the lists:

```
reverseList :: [x] -> [x]
reverseList  [] = []
reverseList  xs = last xs : reverseList (init xs)
```

Then here's the zipper function

```
ZipRevLists2 :: [x] -> [y] -> [(x, y)]
ZipRevLists2 _ [] = []
ZipRevLists2 [] _ = []
ZipRevLists2 (x:xs) = reverseList xs
ZipRevLists2 (y:ys) = reverseList ys
ZipRevLists2 (x:xs) (y:ys) = (x,y) : ZipRev2Lists xs ys
```

I'm trying to learn from learnyouahaskell.com but the only examples are in "ghci>" and not really function form.

Comment: You can either zip then reverse, or reverse (both) separately then zip. Values can't start with uppercase, and all cases must have the same number of arguments. You will have quadratic performance from recursive calls to `last` `init`.

Comment: I'm trying to do the latter where I reverse both separately then zip..  When you say uppercase, do you mean that instead of "ZipRevLists2" I would use "zipRevLists2"?

Comment: Yes I do mean that - uppercase is for types. Try to write out `zip` separately, then combine the helpers `zip`, `reverse` into the overall function you want.

Comment: @moonGoose These are the right suggestions but the wrong words. *Variables* can't start with lowercase. Functions are variables, so this applies here. But values can be uppercase (value constructors), and types can be lowercase (type variables). The important distinction is between variables and constructors, not between values and types.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, I finally got it!

The Zip function

```
zip' :: [x] -> [y] -> [(x,y)]
zip' _ [] = []
zip' [] _ = []
zip' (x:xs) (y:ys) = (x,y):zip' xs ys
```

and the main function

```
zipRevLists2 :: [Int] -> [Char] -> [(Int,Char)]
zipRevLists2 _ [] = []
zipRevLists2 [] _ = []
zipRevLists2 (x:xs) (y:ys) = zip' (reverseList (x:xs))  (reverseList (y:ys))
```

Comment: Since `zip'` (and, presumably, `reverseList`) are already doing the pattern matching for you, you can also simplify a bit: `zipRevLists2 :: ...; zipRevLists2 xs ys = zip' (reverseList xs) (reverseList ys)`.